# Solve recurrence using generating functions if possible.

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I would be obliged if someone could please solve the following recurrence using generating functions:

$a_n-a_{n-1}-2a_{n-2}=4n$

Given that: $a_0=-4, a_1=-5$

I know how to solve this using the usual method (adding general solution and particular solution), but would like to see a generating function approach.

The answer, anyway, is:
$a_n=2^n-2n-5$

Thanks to all!

My efforts:

Let $A(x)=a_0+a_1x+ \cdots +a_nx^n+ \cdots $ be the generating function for the sequence $a_n$.

Then, $A(x)-xA(x)-2x^2A(x)=a_0+(a_1-a_0)x+(a_2-a_1-2a_0)x^2+ \cdots +(a_n-a_{n-1}-2a_{n-2})x^n+ \cdots$ gives the required sequence.

But $A(x)(1-x-2x^2)$ satisfies $4+4x+ \cdots +4x^n+ \cdots$

Or, $$A(x)(1-x-2x^2)=4( \frac 1 {1-x})$$
Simplifying and dividing gives:
$$A(x)= \frac 4 {(1-x^2)(1-2x)}$$

Then, I guess, we split it into partial fractions and get the sequence, right? Please help me out now. Thanks for your help again.

Comment: What are your efforts so far?

Comment: Uploading my efforts.

Comment: Thank you. As a minor quibble, you should also have $A(x)=\cdots+a_n x^n+\cdots$, i.e. it doesn't stop at $x^n$. Unfortunately, your proposed generating function doesn't satisfy a quick consistency check: You would have $A(0)=4$, but $a_0=-4$. I advise looking at the RHS of your $A(x)-x A(x)-2x^2 A(x)=\cdots$ equation and checking whether you have the terms right.

Comment: Thanks sir. If you could provide the full solution, I'd be very obliged since it would help me understand Generating Functions better. I'm new to them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have more or less the right idea, but the right hand side is the sequence $(4n)$, not $(4)$. We have,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty 4n x^n &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty 4(n + 1)x^n - \sum_{n=0}^\infty 4x^n \\
&= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty 4x^{n+1} - \sum_{n=0}^\infty 4x^n \\
&= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\frac{4}{1 - x} - 4\right) - \frac{4}{1 - x} \\
&= \frac{4}{(1 - x)^2} - \frac{4}{1 - x} \\
&= \frac{4x}{(1 - x)^2}.
\end{align*}

As you noted, we have
\begin{align*}
A(x) - xA(x) - 2x^2A(x) &= a_0 + (a_1 - a_0)x + (a_2 - a_1 - 2a_0)x^2 + (a_3 - a_2 - 2a_1)x^3 + \ldots \\
&= a_0 + (a_1 - a_0)x + (4 \cdot 2)x^2 + (4 \cdot 3)x^3 + \ldots + 4n x^n + \ldots \\
&= \frac{4x}{(1 - x)^2} + a_0 + (a_1 - a_0)x - 4x \\
&= \frac{4x}{(1 - x)^2} - 4 + (-5 + 4)x - 4x \\
&= \frac{4x}{(1 - x)^2} - 4 - 5x \\
&= \frac{4x - (4 + 5x)(1 - x)^2}{(1 - x)^2} \\
&= \frac{-5x^3+6x^2+7x-4}{(1 - x)^2} \\
A(x) &= \frac{-5x^3+6x^2+7x-4}{(1 - x)^2(1 - x - 2x^2)} \\
&= \frac{-5x^3+6x^2+7x-4}{(1 - x)^2(1 - 2x)(1 + x)}.
\end{align*}
Before we apply partial fractions, it's worth testing if this fraction can be simplified at all. Plugging in $x = -1$ produces $0$, meaning that $1 + x$ divides it. Dividing out $1 + x$ from the numerator and denominator,
$$A(x) = \frac{-5x^2 + 11x - 4}{(1 - x)^2(1 - 2x)}$$

Now we apply partial fractions. We wish to find $a, b, c$ such that
$$A(x) = \frac{a}{1 - x} + \frac{b}{(1 - x)^2} + \frac{c}{1 - 2x},$$
or equivalently,
$$-5x^2 + 11x - 4 = a(1 - x)(1 - 2x) + b(1 - 2x) + c(1 - x)^2.$$
Considering $x = 1$,
$$-5 \cdot 1^2 + 11 \cdot 1 - 4 = b \cdot (-1) \implies b = -2.$$
Considering $x = \frac{1}{2}$,
$$-5 \cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 + 11 \cdot \frac{1}{2} - 4 = c \cdot \left( \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \cdot \implies c = 1.$$
Now, using these values of $b$ and $c$, we can find $a$ by substituting a different value for $x$, e.g. $x = 0$:
$$-4 = a + (-2) \cdot 1 + 1 \cdot 1^2 \implies a = -3.$$
That is,
$$A(x) = \frac{-3}{1 - x} + \frac{-2}{(1 - x)^2} + \frac{1}{1 - 2x}.$$
We finally convert these generating functions back to sequences:
$$a_n = -3 + (-2)(n + 1) + 2^n = -5 + 2n + 2^n,$$
as required.

Comment: Thank you so much, sir!!!

Comment: Very nicely done (+1)